# How can I stop Parallels Desktop from listing Apps from a VM available in Spotlight?

Tags: spotlight, parallels-desktop

I'm trying to stop Windows apps installed on a VM in Parallels from appearing in Spotlight search results on the host Mac. System details:

- Mac OS: 10.12.6
- Parallels Desktop Business Edition Version: 11.2.3 (32663)
- Windows OS Version (running in Parallels): Windows 10 Pro 1709

I've made sure that in Parallels setting for this VM, the setting Options ➡️ Applications ➡️ Share Windows applications with Mac is set to false:

[image: Parallels Settings]

In addition, as suggested [here](https://forum.parallels.com/threads/remove-windows-os-applications-from-spotlight-search.108061/), I've added `~/Applications (Parallels)/` to the Spotlight privacy blacklist:

[image: Parallels Apps Blacklisted]

Finally, [as suggested by @JMY1000](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308927/how-can-i-stop-parallels-desktop-from-listing-apps-from-a-vm-available-in-spotli#comment391430_308927), I rebuilt the entire Spotlight index on my Mac, by following [these instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716).

And yet still, I can see Windows Apps listed in Spotlight results:

[image]

What can I do to remove Windows apps from Spotlight results?

Comment: [Have you tried rebuilding the spotlight index?](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716)

Comment: @JMY1000 Thanks for the suggestion. I tried, but it did not help.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I just figured it out after searching the sources below.

- System Preferences > Spotlight > Privacy
- Drag your "Applications (Parallels)" folder onto the "Privacy" tab

  - I also added the folder with my Parallels VM (called "Parallels" in screenshot below) just to be sure I wasn't indexing any Parallel's info
- Exiting System Preferences will rebuild the Spotlight index without Parallel's apps

[image]

Note: If you have Alfred installed, go to Alfred Preferences > Advanced > Clear Application Cache

Sources

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SeGQeTrAcn8
2. http://www.zenandmac.com/2013/06/03/how-to-prevent-parallels-applications-from-appearing-in-alfred-search-results/
3. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716

Comment: Similar to Alfred, if you're using Raycast, open its Preferences > Extensions  > Click on "Applications" > Remove the "~/Applications/Parallels" path from the Directories on the right. Raycasts's search will refresh automatically.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me

Mac OS 10.14.5

Parallels Desktop 14 Business Edition version 14.0.1

You have to select Settings of the VM desired. Select Options -> Applications and Uncheck "Share Windows applications with MAC"
 [image]

Then click Disable 
[image]

This method worked for me and now when I search something in Spotlight I don't see any results from my Virtual Machine.